# Merge "delphi-prism" tag into "oxygene"?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I was wondering what the process is for initiating a merge of the above two tags. I'm representing RemObjects Software, the vendor/creator of the Oxygene language. "Delphi Prism" is an old name that was used when Oxygene was licensed to Embarcadero to distribute the product under that name.

Right now, the majority of Oxygene-related questions are tagged with [delphi-prism](/questions/tagged/delphi-prism), and few are tagged with [oxygene](/questions/tagged/oxygene). There's two reasons/arguments for merging the two:

- The "Delphi Prism" brand name is no longer used for the product at all (even the version resold by Embarcadero dropped that branding)
- Having two tags for the same language only serves to spit the already tiny/niche (compared to more mainstream languages) community and their questions

Merging the tags and keeping [oxygene](/questions/tagged/oxygene) would consolidate on the actual proper name of the language, and make it easier for users to find existing questions in one place.

Comment: so, what's the next steps to getting these tags merged (given that i can't merge them myself, afaict)?

Comment: Actually that could be done by synonyms. The master should be Oxygene, the synonym is delphi-prism.

Comment: Then there should be a split of the "oxygene" tag into "oxygene-net" and "oxygene-java" (or "oxygene-android") and others later because "delphi-prism" refers ONLY to Oxygene for .NET, right?

Comment: @d.cornelius: All current Delphi Prism questions could safely be moved into an `oxygene-net` or `oxygene` tag. Although a split would probably be better (at least into `oxygene-net` and `oxygene-java`), at this point there aren't any `oxygene-java` questions I can find even under the generic `oxygene` tag. So a merge of `delphi-prism` into `oxygene` and then a rename of `oxygene` into `oxygene-net` would be perfectly acceptable, IMO.

Comment: imho there's few enough Oxygene questions so far as to NOT warrant a split of the oxygene community into three separate tags? Questions can be dual-tagged with "oxygene" and ".NET", or "oxygene" and "Java" where appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I can see for not merging the tags is that there are answers that apply to Delphi Prism that don't apply to Oxygene. If a question that is asked about Delphi Prism would have a different answer if asked about Oxygene, then the question should be tagged [delphi-prism](/questions/tagged/delphi-prism), not [oxygene](/questions/tagged/oxygene).
If there isn't any difference between Delphi Prism and Oxygene, then I would merge the two tags, and make [oxygene](/questions/tagged/oxygene) the main tag.

In the case there are questions that apply to Delphi Prism but not Oxygene (or vice versa), then this case is similar to  the one of [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7) and [drupal-8](/questions/tagged/drupal-8). Drupal 8 and Drupal 7 are so different that they are like two different *products*; if I merge the tags, I would create confusion, since what applies to Drupal 7 could not apply to Drupal 8.

Comment: since "Delphi Prism" was just a different branding for the Oxygene product, there should be no room for questions being "Delphi Prism" specific and not being applicable to the "Oxygene" tag. IOW, please do go ahead and merge the tags (i don't have the necessary Reputation to do it myself yet, i'm afraid).

Comment: I just can confirm what marc hoffman says. Oxygene was sold by Embarcadero under the label Delphi Prism, but in fact it's the very same product.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi Prism was just a rebranding of Oxygene. All questions about Delphi Prism are actually questions about Oxygene. Delphi Prism is no longer a product, but the Oxygene name (which predated Prism) continues to be around. They should be merged.